# How can I enable protocol traffic with firewalld?

Tags: iptables, firewall

I need to allow Protocol 50 (esp) traffic for ipsec.

I can do:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p esp
iptables -A OUTPUT -p esp
```

How could I do this with firewalld instead?

Comment: For further reference, here's the first Google result for your question: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD

It has a lot of examples, including one that's precisely what you're asking for (with ah instead of esp).

Comment: @gparent There are no add-rich-rule examples, nor any examples using non-tcp/udp protocols. Are you looking at a different page than you linked? Also, that link doesn't show up on any of the first 5 pages for my question, so... did you search something different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a (fairly simple) rich rule for this.

For example:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=vpnendpoint --add-rich-rule="rule protocol value=esp accept"
```

Comment: In case someone else sees, the syntax is `--add-rich-rule="protocol value=esp accept"`

Comment: Can you please provide service.xml method of declaring this?

Answer (score 2):

This post is obsolete for newer versions of firewalld.

If anyone comes by this post as of when I'm looking at it (2023-01-21), firewalld has a definition for esp, so you don't need to do these more complicated rules, any more...

`firewall-cmd --add-protocol=esp`

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means an iptables or firewalld expert, but it seems to me something like this would work:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule filter INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule filter OUTPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
```

If you have zones and such all setup, you could also do it with the `--zone` and `--add-rich-rule` options instead of `--direct`.